# Rails form maxlength for rich_text fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After updating a plain text field to a rich_text_area like shown below, the maxlength property doesn't get applied - so the field now has no limit.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.rich_text_area :description, class: 'form-control',  maxlength: 150 %>
  </div>
```

Is there a maxlength option for rich_text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails `FormHelper#rich_text_area` return a `trix-editor` and it looks like [trix-editor doesn't support max-length attribute](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/253#issuecomment-228623229).

this maybe a [workaround](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/571#issuecomment-441051534)

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js
import "../views/trix_editor_extension"

// app/javascript/views/trix_editor_extension.js
const MaxLength = 200;
window.addEventListener("trix-change", function(event) {
  const { editor } = event.target;
  const string = editor.getDocument().toString();
  if(string.length > MaxLength) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // truncate string or show alert
    alert(".......................");
  }
})
```